# Parsing a PDF file using PDFBox - Columns overlap

Tags: java, parsing, pdf, pdfbox

I've got a PDF file and I need to parse it with layout. I am using Apache PDFBox in order to parse the PDF and using PDFLayoutTextStripper class for layout.

[image: Sample PDF]

I am giving an example from the Sample PDF image. On the row of 120.01.191; the column with text, which starts with "LODOS KUNDURA - NEVZAT BALIKÇI AYAK.İML", overflows to the next column, therefore, while the application is reading the next column, I got a result such as '.TAO 3 P4.4 S .A 94 T9. ,66'. The problem is the second and the third column merges into one. I want them seperatly as "LODOS KUNDURA - NEVZAT BALIKÇI AYAK.İMLAT PAS. / 344949.66".

Is there a way to avoid this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using the `PDFLayoutTextStripper`, then you want a representation which tries to put characters where they actually are located. In your case there is an overlap. Thus, it is quite plausible that the overlapping text pieces get mangled into each other. (The mangling appears partially unnecessary but I doubt there is an easy way to get your desired result.) An option might be, though, to ignore non-visible characters, at lest if one can restrict oneself to e.g. invisibility due to clip paths.